# How to identify when the values passed to the constructor of a Record subclass are invalid in Immutable.JS?

Tags: immutable.js

I know that Record subclasses do not accept key value pairs from the constructor if the key name is not defined originally in the subclass. However, I want to be able to identify when a invalid key pair is being passed in the constructor of my Record.

For example,

```
export default class MessageTester extends Record ({
    successStatus: null,
    message: null,
}) {
    constructor(dataSet) {
         /* Pseudo-code
          * if (dataSet keys do not match MessageTester keys) {
          *     console.log('Keys passed to constructor do not match.');
          */
          super(dataSet);
    }

}
```

I thought about retrieving the keys from both the dataSet and the MessageTester and comparing them, but then I came up with another solution. I would test the keys by retrieving the keys from the dataSet value. I cannot get the get method for Records to work inside the class using the this keyword. Any solutions to my main issue listed above would be terrific.

```
let dataSetKeys = Object.keys(dataSet);
for (let i = 0; i < dataSetKeys.length; i++) {
    if(this.get(dataSetKeys[i]) === undefined)
        console.log('Invalid key found.');
}
```

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem for this code. let dataSetKeys = Object.keys(dataSet);
for (let i = 0; i < dataSetKeys.length; i++) {
    if(this.get(dataSetKeys[i]) === undefined)
        console.log('Invalid key found.');
}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I at least figured out a solution for the bottm snippet of code. I should have been using super istead of this since get is a methond of Record..... Sorry, simple mistake on my part. Curious though, is there a better solution?

```
let dataSetKeys = Object.keys(dataSet);
for (let i = 0; i < dataSetKeys.length; i++) {
    if(super.get(dataSetKeys[i]) === undefined)
        console.log('Invalid key found.');
}
```

Comment: This does not works since I have not called the super constructor yet. Just realized that.